# MySQL Union for two tables, then merge in a third table where matched?

Tags: mysql, union, distinct

I have three MySQL tables that I'm trying to query into a single result. As close as I've gotten this, I think it's possible, but I've hit a wall in getting the last part working.

Basically I have two tables (table_one and table_two) which I'm trying to UNION DISTINCT, which works perfectly. It's when I try to bring in the third table that it all blows up and decides to return nothing. I'm sure it's user error  :)

This code may not have everything in the right place for how I'm trying to do it, so maybe I just need a little nudge in the right direction.

```
SELECT
    part_code,
    name
FROM
    table_three

WHERE
    table_three.part_code = (

    SELECT
        part_code
    FROM
        table_one

    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT
        part_code
    FROM
        table_two
)

ORDER BY
    name ASC
```

I appreciate any direction someone can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHERE
    table_three.part_code IN(
                          ^^
```

**Edit**
Here are some alternatives that satisfies: *Gief all rows in Table 3 such that the part code exists in either Table 1 or Table 2*.

```
select t3.part_code
      ,t3.name
  from table_three t3
 where part_code in(select t1.part_code from table_one t1)
    or part_code in(select t2.part_code from table_two t2);
```

Derived table with union

```
select t3.part_code
      ,t3.name
  from table_three t3
  join (select part_code from table_one 
         union
        select part_code from table_two
       ) t12
     on(t3.part_code = t12.part_code);
```

Inner join with union

```
select t3.part_code
      ,t3.name
  from table_three t3
  join table_one   t1 on(t3.part_code = t1.part_code)
union   
select t3.part_code
      ,t3.name
  from table_three t3
  join table_two   t2 on(t3.part_code = t2.part_code);
```

Bonus. I have no idea why I did this.

```
select t3.part_code
      ,t3.name
  from table_three t3
  left join (select distinct part_code 
                      from table_one) t1 on(t3.part_code = t1.part_code)
  left join (select distinct part_code 
                      from table_two) t2 on(t3.part_code = t2.part_code)
 where t3.part_code = t1.part_code
    or t3.part_code = t2.part_code;
```

Let me know how they work out.

**Edit 2.**
Ok, try the following. It should produce the union of tables T1 and T2. Then for each row, it will pick the name from T3 if such a part code can be found.

If part_code is a key in all tables, you can do a `UNION ALL` instead.

```
select T12.part_code
      ,coalesce(T3.name, T12.name) as name
  from (select part_code, name from table_one T1 union   
        select part_code, name from table_two T2
       ) T12
  left join table_three T3 on(T1.part_code = T3.part_code);
```

Comment: That looked promising, but it got me this error in phpMyAdmin:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: Here's what I've got right now, with the above error:

`SELECT part_code,name FROM table_three WHERE table_three.part_code = IN(
 SELECT part_code FROM table_one UNION DISTINCT (
  SELECT part_code FROM table_two
 )
)
ORDER BY
 name ASC`

Comment: @Will Ashworth, remove the equal sign before the "IN" keyword

Comment: OMG. That was so unbelievably simple...the first example did it. How in the heck did I not try that?! You're awesome for this great example. I think it will help others, as I tried to be as descript as possible for others searching to find this post.

Comment: Actually, maybe I could have been a little clearer. Regardless, your queries fixed the primary issue of first joining/merging the information perfectly. Table three is supplemental to tables one/two and optional. If the name field has a match add it, otherwise name field in our returned result will be empty. Table three is secondary and what's happening right now in these examples is table one/two's data is getting trimmed from the result, because it's using three as a master somehow.

Comment: ....In other words, I'm getting 67 results returned (cause that's how many rows are in table three) when I should be getting like 200.

Comment: @Will Ashworth, Table 3 is the driver/master in all of my examples. If you take my requirement (written in italics) and rephrase it to your real requirement, I can help you find the correct query as well.

Comment: Yeah, I think what I'm trying to do is slightly different. Instead I need to get "all rows in Table 1 and Table 2 (combined data) and if the part code exists in Table 3, merge the name from Table 3". The combined data for Table 1 and Table 2 are my master list of products.

This is all a legacy data structure, so I'm working with a complicated setup to begin with and attempting to code around what's already been invested in formerly. Thanks for your help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :)

```
SELECT
    part_code,
    name
FROM 
    table_three

WHERE
   table_three.part_code = (

SELECT
    part_code
FROM
    table_one

UNION DISTINCT (
SELECT
    part_code
FROM
    table_two

 ))

ORDER BY
   name ASC;
```

Comment: Tried that too. I get MySQL error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

select * into table_name from(
select * from #tb1
union
select * from #tb2
)a

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).